# PowerShell - $collection.GetEnumerator() method for sort

Tags: powershell

I was excuting the powershell script with below sort command. it is giving me an error as "system collection dictionary entry does not contain a method name substring". I want to write out sort records from 9th column/record in Out_File, Could anyone help me with this?

```powershell
$collection.GetEnumerator() | sort Name| foreach {$_.substring(9)} | Out-File $SORTED_AUDIT -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: How is $collection defined?  What is the result of `$collection.GetType()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type `$collection` is, though if it's any of the built in types then you probably don't need the GetEnumerator() call, as Powershell will automatically GetEnumerator on any IEnumerable in the pipeline.

For now I will assume `$collection` is a collection of objects with properties.  It has at least one property `Name` by which you're sorting it, and at least one string property that you want to drop the last 9 characters of.  In that case, you need to take the substring of the property, and not of $_

```
$collection | sort Name | foreach { $_.string_property.substring(9) } | out-File $SORTED_AUDIT -Encoding ascii
```

If you only want to pass the mystery string to Out-File, and not the whole object, then you would instead use Select-Object to choose the property prior to your foreach

```
$collection | sort Name | Select -Property string_property | foreach {$_.substring(9)} | Out-File etc.
```